# Remove automatic mount of external HDD

Tags: mount

I have a external HDD that is mounting automatically on my rpi. Thing is I don't use it anymore, it makes noise, and if I disconnect it, rpi won't boot, until I connect it.

I checked /etc/fstab, but I don't have the entry of my hdd.

Here is my fstab

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/sdb1    /home/pi/Bureau/ssd    ext4    defaults,rw,user,exec,auto    0    0
```

/ is my microSD

/dev/sdb1 is a ssd drive, this one is used

Where should I look to disable automount ???

EDIT:

Output of mount:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/log $ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=470120k,nr_inodes=117530,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p6 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/pi/Bureau/ssd type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,user)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94944k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p5 on /media/pi/SETTINGS type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/HDD type ntfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: how is it mounted - i.e. what is the output of `mount`

Comment: I don't know. how should I see it ? Any log file ?

Comment: what is the output of `mount` - you should see in the output of `mount` command where this device is mounted

Comment: oh ok, after connecting again the hdd, I have an extraline: /dev/sda1 on /media/pi/HDD type ntfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: do you use your pi through GUI or CLI?

Comment: you will have better luck posting the question on a linux site .... the question is not RPi related

Comment: What OS? Your mount and fstab don't look like any recent Raspbian or NOOBS.

Comment: Looks like a udisks autopolling problem... [here's something similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342736/how-do-i-disable-my-cd-dvd-drive) ... you should be able to watch the drive automount by checking the status of udisks2 in systemd ... `systemctl status udisks2` ... and then plug in the drive.

Comment: Looks like the lxde automount to me. Can be disabled in pcmanfm (File Manager). Menu Edit / Preferences

Comment: @Rubberstamp udisk2.service could not be found

Comment: @Dirk I unchecked it, and now HDD is not auto mounted after reboot, but problem remains the same, os will not boot if HDD is unplugged

Comment: if the OS doesn't boot when HDD is unplugged, then there's something on the HDD that is required for booting - which is odd

Comment: Please answer the question from *Milliways*: what OS?

Comment: @Milliways  I used noobs to install raspbian June 2018

Comment: I manually added the line: /dev/sdb1 to customize the folder where it is mounted

Comment: @JaromandaX I think this is the right track, but I don't really know how to investigate any dependency

Comment: This may be a UUID issue.  You've got a drive listed in fstab... but it's listed as sdb ... but there is no sdb because you've removed sda from the system.  Try changing `fstab` to list `sda` for the drive that you wish to continue using... or even better [convert the entry to UUID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137862/why-does-fstab-use-uuid-instead-of-the-actual-file-system-name) instead... you can find out the drive's UUID via `lsblk -o NAME,UUID,MOUNTPOINT`

Comment: @RubberStamp you are right. Sdb with only disk was a problem. Fixed changing sdb to sda. I will try uuid now ! Please put it as answer! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that the manually added `/etc/fstab` entry is enumerated by kernel device name rather than UUID.  When a block device is detected by the kernel, it is assigned a name such as `sda` or `sdb`.  The partitions are assigned sequential numbers such as `sda1 sda2` or `sdb1 sdb2`.  These are assigned according to when the kernel detects a device and not assigned per specific device.  This means that if you have two external USB hard drives, they will be assigned different device names if attached in a different order.  The first drive to be attached will always be `sda`.  Because of this, the fstab entries may not match the actual devices that are expected to be mounted.

Your particular problem is that your fstab enumerates an sdb device, but there is no sdb device due to the removal of what used to be sda.

To avoid such confusion, it is advisable to identify mount devices by their UUID in `/etc/fstab`, especially for removable devices such as USB external hard drives.

As indicated in this [Unix/Linux fstab Question/Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137862/why-does-fstab-use-uuid-instead-of-the-actual-file-system-name) you can easily obtain the UUID of any block device via the `blkid` command. And as indicated in the example, UUID entries in `/etc/fstab` should have the following format:

```
# UUID=Number                                     Mount Point      FS Type         Options         Dump Freq          FS Check
UUID=72bfc10d-73ec-4d9e-a54a-1cc507ee7ed2         /media/test        ext4            defaults          0                   0
```

So, you should either change the fstab entry so that the device listed matches the device name the kernel is assigning.  Change `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sda1`.

Or, for a much more robust solution, switch the fstab entry to UUID enumeration.

See `man fstab` or the online [fstab manual page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) for more information on specific file system options and parameters.

Comment: Adding the nofail option will continue the boot process even if that device can't be mounted.